# SQL Server's aggregate functions ignore nulls. How do I correct this?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, null

According to [MS's knowledgebase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx),

> Except for COUNT, aggregate functions ignore null values.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work correctly, that is, return a null if it attempts to aggregate with a null in the values?

Example:

```
SELECT SUM("col")
FROM (
    SELECT NULL "col"
    UNION
    SELECT 1 "col"
) test
```

I would expect this query to return `NULL`, not 1.

Comment: This is a behaviour defined in the SQL standard. If you want a different behaviour, write the appropriate query - say with `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... WHERE column iS NULL)`

Comment: In other words, it already works correctly. Problem solved.

Comment: Aggregate functions are NOT concatenation operators. And as @ypercube mentioned this is defined in the SQL Standard.

Comment: Note that the behavior is arguably different depending on the aggregate. Replace SUM with COUNT to see what I mean. In fact I would argue that COUNT ignores NULL as well.

Comment: Not sure why this merited a downvote, @ypercube...

Comment: @end-user Why do you think you know who down-voted?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps because you wrote *"how I can get it to work correctly" while you meant *"how I can get it to work the way I want it"*

Comment: Your saying "how I can get it to work correctly" seems to imply that the documented behaviour is not correct. So, perhaps someone disagreed with that premise, considering such a question not useful.

Comment: The knowledgebase documentation is incorrect. COUNT most definitely ignores null values, as it should

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simulate this by applying a where clause to your query:

```
with test_data (col) as (
   select null union all 
   select 1 union all
   select 2
)
select sum(col)
from test_data
where not exists (select 1 
                  from test_data
                  where col is null);
```

**Edit**

Andriy is right, this can also be written as:

```
with test_data (col) as (
   select null union all 
   select 1 union all
   select 2
)
select case 
          when count(*) = count(col) then sum(col)
          else null
       end
from test_data;
```

Comment: Seems a little overkill. You could just compare `COUNT(col)` and `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @AndriyM: good point, I added that as well. Thanks